# Upload image with jquery and display results

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I know this is a typical question but i've tried alot of things and haven't got it to work yet. I have a form where i want to upload an image, and as i've come to understand jquery natively doesent support imageupload in form submits. So we begin with the html i have:

```
<form action="uploadImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image_form" name="image_form">                                                                                                           

<input type="file" name="addImage"  />                                                      

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />    

                                    </form> 
<div id="results">
</div>
```

And then we have the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                                        $('#image_form').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
                                            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                                                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                                                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                                                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                                                success: function(response) { // on success..
                                                    $('#results').load('Images.php'); // update the DIV
                                                }
                                            });
                                            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
                                        });
                                        });
```

Something tells me i need an implentation of http://malsup.com/jquery/ but i don't really understand how. And my php script for image upload works fine and is great, so it would be cool if I just could use the forms action but submit it with jquery.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serialize file inputs. To upload something asynchronously and make it work in all browsers, you need to use the hidden iframe trick. I'd recommend finding a jQuery plugin for that. [Here is one you can try.](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use some plugin like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: Anyone who has downloaded Uploadify between July 1, 2011 and July 11, 2011 will need to re-download the zip package.  Some users informed me that some hackers were able to modify my download packages with some sketchy code.  Basically, they added a line of code at the bottom of the uploadify.php file that would email [...] (http://www.uploadify.com/news/security-warning/)